# Точки (Placemark) вдоль маршрута

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты

Вопрос таков, как можно лучше и быстрее показать точки рядом с маршрутом (multiRoute).

Делал 2 варианта, первый это обрисовать маршрут прямоугольниками и показать те точки что попали в них, однако в рамках города это не подходит ибо криво.

Варианта 2 это разбить на сегменты и найти ближайшие точки, однако и тут не все гладко.

Делаю вот так, но что то не то, а именно дистанция считается не верно, вопрос почему . Может от Плейсмарка до сегмента не верно считает ? Но как он вообще считает?

В myCollection лежат PlaceMark.

Код ниже:

```
  $scope.mMap.geoObjects.add($scope.multiRoute);



        $scope.multiRoute.events.add("update",function () {

                    var wayPoints = $scope.multiRoute.getWayPoints();



                    $scope.myCollection.each(function (GeoPoint) {

                        GeoPoint.options.set('visible',0);

                    });





                    $scope.multiRoute.getRoutes().each(function (route) {

                        console.log('route data:', route.properties.getAll());

                        route.getPaths().each(function (path) {

                            //console.log('path data:', path.properties.getAll());

                            path.getSegments().each(function (segment) {

                                //console.log('segment data:', segment.properties.getAll());

                                 $scope.myCollection.each(function (GeoPoint) {

                                       console.log(GeoPoint.geometry.getType()); 

                                      if(GeoPoint.geometry && GeoPoint.geometry.getType() === 'Point') { 

                                        var obj=segment.geometry.getClosest(GeoPoint.geometry.getCoordinates());

                                        //console.log(obj.distance);

                                        if (obj.distance < 1000){

                                            console.log(obj.distance,GeoPoint.geometry.getCoordinates(),"DIST");

                                            GeoPoint.options.set('visible',1);

                                        } else {

                                          GeoPoint.options.set('visible',0);

                                        }

                                      }



                                    });



                            });

                        });

                    });

        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Считается неправильно, скорее всего, потому что вы прячете и показываете каждый Placemark для каждого сегмента.

Попробуйте вначале собрать маршрут в линию, а затем делать фильтрацию:

```js
ymaps.ready([
  'Map', 'multiRouter.MultiRoute', 'GeoObjectCollection', 'Polyline'
]).then(function() {
  const map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.75, 37.62],
    zoom: 8,
    controls: []
  });
  
  // Создаем мульти-маршрут.
  var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
    referencePoints: ['Шереметьево', 'Домодедово']
  });
  map.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
  
  // Создаем метки.
  const placemarks = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection({
    children: generatePlacemarks(map.getBounds(), 10)
  });
  map.geoObjects.add(placemarks);
  
  // Пороговое расстояние в метрах.
  const threshold = 7500;

  // Как только мульти-маршрут загрузится.
  multiRoute.events.once('update', function() {
    // Собираем по линии для каждой нитки маршрута.
    const lineGeoObjects = multiRoute.getRoutes().toArray()
      .map(route => new ymaps.Polyline(routeToLineString(route)));
    
    // Добавляем линии на карту, т.к. getClosest нужна информация о проекции.
    const lines =  new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(
      { children: lineGeoObjects },
      { visible: false });
    map.geoObjects.add(lines);
    
    // Обновляем visible для каждой метки.
    placemarks.each(function(placemark) {
      const coords = placemark.geometry.getCoordinates();
      
      // Вычисляем если расстояние хотя бы до одной нитки меньше порогового.
      const isNearSomeRoute = lines.toArray()
        .some(line => {
          const closest = line.geometry.getClosest(coords);
          return closest.distance < threshold;
        });

      placemark.options.set('visible', isNearSomeRoute);
    });
  });
}).catch(console.error);

function routeToLineString(route) {
  const points = route.getPaths().toArray()
    .map(x => x.getSegments().toArray())
    .reduce((s, x) => s.concat(x), []) // flatten
    .map(x => x.geometry.getCoordinates())
    .reduce((s, x) => s.concat(x), []); // flatten

  // Сюда можно добавить симплификацию линии для ускорения
  // поиска расстояния.

  return { type: 'LineString', coordinates: points };
}

/** Генерирует n x n меток */
function generatePlacemarks(bounds, n) {
  const result = [];
  const latstep = (bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0]) / n;
  const lonstep = (bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1]) / n;
  for (let row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < n; col++) {
      result.push(new ymaps.Placemark([
          bounds[0][0] + latstep * (0.5 + row),
          bounds[0][1] + lonstep * (0.5 + col)
        ],
        { iconContent: row + ',' + col },
        { preset: 'islands#circleIcon' })
      );
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&mode=debug"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px"></div>
```