# Разбор примера маршрута от МКАД

Tags: yandex-maps-api

В песочнице есть, пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/route_inside_polygon

В нем все ясно, но у меня так и не получается получить длину отрезка от МКАД.
т.е. после удаления отрезков входящих в область МКАД и перекрестных сегментов у меня остается сегмент за МКАД

```
objectsOutMoscow = routeObjects.remove(objectsInMoscow).remove(boundaryObjects);
```

Вот его длину не могу получить в километрах, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать!

Answer (score 1):

Для меня подошло решение вот такое... не уверен, что оно правильное, но в данный момент работает

```js
var points = [];
for (var i = 0; i < objectsOutMoscow._objects.length; i++) {
    points.push(
        objectsOutMoscow._objects[i].geometry._bounds[0]
    );
}
var lineStringGeometry = new ymaps.geometry.LineString(points),
    geoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
        geometry: lineStringGeometry
    });
myMap.geoObjects.add(geoObject);
console.log((geoObject.geometry.getDistance()) / 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Соберите маршрут как показано в этом вопросе: [Точки (Placemark) вдоль маршрута](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756685/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-placemark-%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0#)

А дальше найдите его длину с помощью:

```
polyline.geometry.getDistance();
```

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geometry.LineString-docpage/#method_detail__getDistance

Comment: не подходит. мне не нужно считать длину всего маршрута, а только за МКАД, выехать могут из любой точки внутри, и как только выезжаем на МКАД пошел счетчик. Отрезок я получил из официального примера в песочнице и смог получить дистанцию при явном указании координат `ymaps.coordSystem.geo.getDistance([55.137649357923,40.385404355901], [56.137649357923,40.385404355901]` вот как из objectsOutMoscow в котором точки выдернуть перую и последнюю координату?

Comment: ymaps.coordSystem.geo.getDistance получает расстояние напрямую, а не по дорогам. Это то чего вы хотите?

Comment: Выше я описал как реализовал. т.е. использовал код из песочницы и добавил свое.